# Unable to install sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, ssl, sfdx-plugin

I am using 1.38.1 version of VSCode and i have done

> "http.proxyStrictSSL": false

I am still getting error

***Error: unable to get local issuer certificate***

i tried in my personal laptop. Now getting following error

```
 warning @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @lwc/style-compiler > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @lwc/style-compiler > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.hed digital signature check.
warning @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @lwc/style-compiler > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > caniuse-api > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @lwc/style-compiler > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > postcss-selector-parser > flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
warning @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @salesforce/command > @oclif/test > fancy-test > @types/nock@11.1.0: This is a stub types definition. nock provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
warning @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @salesforce/core > @salesforce/ts-sinon > sinon > @sinonjs/formatio > samsam@1.3.0: This package has been deprecated in favour of @sinonjs/samsam
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@salesforce/lwc-dev-server-dependencies/-/lwc-dev-server-dependencies-1.0.47.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
C:\Users\Sidhartha Mohapatra\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.27.0-714f62f9c1\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:78070
    compromised = compromised || function (err) { throw err; };
                                                  ^

Error: Unable to update lock within the stale threshold
    at options.fs.utimes (C:\Users\Sidhartha Mohapatra\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.27.0-714f62f9c1\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:77992:66)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server... !
Error: yarn add @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:/Users/Sidhartha Mohapatra/AppData/Local/sfdx/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=C:/Users/Sidhartha Mohapatra/AppData/Local/sfdx/yarn --check-files exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.forked.on (C:/Users/Sidhartha Mohapatra/AppData/Local/sfdx/client/7.27.0-714f62f9c1/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)
```

has anyone faced this issue and tried any workaround

Answer (score 2):

found the solution .. Just need to trick Node that there is a certificate present, if people are working in office network..

Downloaded the certificate -

> https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt

Ran the below command -

> npm config set cafile /path/to/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt

after this i was able to install within corporate network

Comment: Some more details would make this a better answer. How, precisely, do you trick node into thinking there is a cert? Good answers are those where other people can understand and apply them themselves (without needing to dig around for other resources).

Comment: updated my answer..