# Local server connection Issue with Lightning Web Component in VS Code

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I was trying to connect local server with the lightning web component in Vs code.I have written the following command in terminal

**sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server**

But I am getting this following error

**Error: Unable to update lock within the stale threshold
at C:\Program Files\sfdx\client\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:78645:66
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:23) {
code: 'ECOMPROMISED'
}
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server... failed
Error: yarn add @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive
--mutex=file:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn.lock
--preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn --check-files exited with

code 1**

Could anyone please help in this issue?

Comment: Here is a similar [SFSE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280736/unable-to-install-sfdx-pluginsinstall-salesforce-lwc-dev-server). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this issue before and reinstalling both npm and sfdx has solved my issue.

refer to few of these links for more solutions:

- [github issues for repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/issues/3)
- [SF dev forum question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000R0FqQAK)